# Setting IonDatetime default value while using watch function from react-hook-form

Tags: ionic-framework, react-hook-form, ionic-react, ionic6

I'm building a form using Ionic 6, React 18 and react-hook-form 7.37.0.

My form includes a field where a datetime needs to be set, which is implemented with `IonDatetime`.

Using `minuteValues` parameter I limit the user to select minutes values in 5 minutes increments.
This works fine. However, IonDatetime is including a default time that does not follow this restriction, any minute value can appear as default. I'd like to have a valid minute value as a default value. I have tried to set a default valid time with `value` parameter but I've found out that it interferes with the use of the `watch` function of `react-hook-form`.

If I `watch` the IonDatetime field, I cannot set any other value than the default value. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ionic6-datetime-and-react-hook-form-default-value-9xoz3l?file=/src/pages/FormPage.tsx) there is a minimal example of this.

I also leave here the most relevant part of the code.

```
  const birthTime = watch("birthTime");


  <IonItem {...register("birthTime")} button={true} id="open-datetime">
        <IonLabel>Birth time</IonLabel>
        {birthTime !== "" ? (
          <IonText>
            {format(parseISO(birthTime!), "dd MM yyyy HH:mm")}
          </IonText>
        ) : (
          <IonText class="placeholder">Select a date</IonText>
        )}

        <IonModal ref={modal} trigger="open-datetime">
          <IonContent>
            <IonDatetime
              min="2022-09-18T12:23"
              max="2022-10-12T17:22"
              value="2022-09-23T15:00"
              minuteValues="0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55"
              onIonChange={(ev: any) => {
                setValue(
                  "birthTime",
                  dateFormat(
                    (ev.detail.value as unknown) as Date,
                    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM"
                  )
                );
              }}
            />
            <IonButton
              onClick={() => {
                dismiss();
              }}
            >
              Close
            </IonButton>
          </IonContent>
        </IonModal>
      </IonItem>
```